# can i stop a iframe, before it is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, privacy

I have some websites with different google maps embeds.(iframe) I read a lot of about data protection and privacy policy in the last few month. There are a lot of risk in relation with google maps.
Now i want to use a validation button for the user, before the google maps are loaded.

I'll do that with jQuery.
My idea is to delete the src from the iframes and show a warrning notice like "If you click continue, you will accept the google maps privacy policy. see here"

after click the button, the maps are loaded.

My solution:

1. jQuery -> document.ready -> loop to find all iframes -> check if google maps -> save src url in a variable or write it in a data-tag from the iframe tag -> show warning notice
2. if click on button, get src from data tag, or variable. set it as src for the iframe and load the map.

BUT... I'm not sure if it is "fast" enough.
If someone open my site, i does take a few seconds for trigger the document.ready event and some seconds again, for loading the whole site... Is it possible, that the iframe loads the google maps and send some personal data, before my loop clear the src from the iframe????

thank you for your help

Comment: You should change the `src` attribute of your iframe to something else, like `data-src`. Then loop over each iframe[data-src] element and, if the user has given consent, set the src attribute. Otherwise the browser will instantly fetch the source even if you change the src IMMEDIATELY after the element was added to the DOM.

Comment: Why not having all these google iFrames with a `src="about:blank"` by default and a data attribute, then setting the `src` only when validated?

Comment: Ha! the time it took to check if an empty `src` was valid, you posted the same comment :P

Comment: i thought i can do it a little bit easier like a loop. because it's a lot of work to edit each iframe....

Comment: You can do a search and replace easily with most text editors, even some can use regexes and search in multiple files like Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your HTML code, you can set the src attribute of the iframe to an empty value:

```
<iframe id="mapFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

Then, in your jQuery code, you can assign the Google Maps URL to the src attribute when the user clicks on the validation button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Store the Google Maps URL
  var googleMapsURL = "https://maps.google.com/your-maps-url";

  // Remove the src attribute initially
  $("#mapFrame").attr("src", "");

  // Show warning notice and handle button click
  $("#validationButton").click(function() {
    // Set the Google Maps URL as the src attribute
    $("#mapFrame").attr("src", googleMapsURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks like i need to change everything by myself